# best tool / programming language for data visualization

Tags: data-visualization

Up till now I mostly used excel to plot any data I retrieve from MySQL using PHP,
(with occasionally a JS library like HighCharts to plot data). 
This is not really an option when I want more complex charts/visualizations or if there are to many records (excel gets slooooow) so I'm looking for alternatives. However, there are so many options! I've downloaded and tried things like R and Processing several times but I'm not convinced yet this is the right tool for 'just' charting my data in a nice way.

So... im curious to here opinions about the best way to go. Learn Python? Really dive into Java/processing? any other options? 
(or stick with PHP and you have a real flexible graphing library available? ;) )

Answer (score 4):

I think Python is great for quick and rich data processing.

Answer (score 2):

Personally I find that [Incanter](http://incanter.org/) is a great toolset that I can heartily recommend (I use it for visualisation in my own projects).

It's a statistical computing and visualisation library for Clojure - which in turn is a very powerful, flexible and dynamic langauge, particularly suited for interactive experiments with data

Nice features:

- Numerics provide by [parallel colt](http://sourceforge.net/projects/parallelcolt/)
- Charts are generated using the very comprehensive [JFreeChart library](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/)
- It also uses [Processing](http://processing.org/) for some visualizations
- Clojure in itself is a great language for data processing and exploration
- Interop with Java is excellent, so you can use any Java libraries easily (for stuff like database access, web services, message queue integration, networking etc.)

I particularly like the DSL for creating charts, e.g. to create a histogram of 1000 samples from the normal distribution you can just do:

```
(view (histogram (sample-normal 1000)))
```

Answer (score 2):

I highly recommend using Vega-Lite & Vega for data visualizations, from whatever language you chose. Vega-Lite & Vega are designed based on the ideas of the Grammar of Graphics, which inspired R's popular ggplot2 library. The core idea is that data visualizations should be built according to declarative descriptions of how properties of the data map to aesthetics of the dataviz. Vega-Lite & Vega however take things one step further in providing a grammar of *interaction*, which allows for the construction of interactive data visualizations and sophisticated explorer views. Moreover, it ups the ante on the declarative nature of the GG in that Vega-Lite and Vega specifications are described as pure data (JSON). Thus, any language that can reasonably target JSON can target Vega-Lite & Vega.

Vega-Lite is more or less the higher lever, day-to-day data science tool, focusing on providing high leverage and automation based on very spartan specifications. It compiles to Vega, which is a somewhat lower level and more powerful, but less automated version of Vega-Lite. Usually starting out with Vega-Lite, and switching to Vega only as needed is sufficient.

For more on Vega & Vega-Lite see: https://vega.github.io.

On a final note, I'll second the sentiment of mikera and Ravinder Ram's that Clojure is a great language for data science, and is getting better all the time with new machine learning libraries (e.g. MXNet just [recently got Clojure support](https://github.com/apache/incubator-mxnet/tree/master/contrib/clojure-package)). There's also now support for most of the modern scientific notebook environments (Jupyter, Nextjournal, Gorilla REPL), if that's your thing.

If you'd like to use Vega-Lite or Vega from Clojure or ClojureScript, you may wish to check out a small but flexible wrapper library I wrote called Oz:

https://github.com/metasoarous/oz

If you're interested in using Vega-Lite or Vega from other languages, there are lots to pick from because of how simple it is to wrap (e.g. Python, R, React).

Answer (score 1):

I think incanter clojure library for statistic and data visualization. clojure is functional and excellent in data processing and analytics

Answer (score 0):

Python, Octave, C/C++ and so on. There are a lot of libraries for plotting for each of them.

I can recommend GPL plotting library [MathGL](http://mathgl.sf.net/) and its front-end [UDAV](http://udav.sf.net/). Last one have another command language for plotting.

Answer (score 0):

R language is mostly used for data science - you can make complicated mathematical data manipulations and build predictive models, but it will neither help you with its convenience nor with easy-to-go graphics. I don't think that you need Java unless you are going to have some complicated business-logic or multi-threading.

So I would recommend to stick to Python - it is really convenient for data processing, easy to learn. Actually, working with data is the strength of Python. You can also choose of [multiple](https://blog.modeanalytics.com/python-data-visualization-libraries/)(the link is a good compilation, found it on the Internet) data visualization libraries or try javascript on top. Don't be afraid and good luck!

Answer (score 0):

I personally started using [Python](https://www.python.org/)+[D3.js](https://d3js.org/).

Python is great technology to work with data - to manage, transform and output in different formats.

And D3.js is a great library for data visualization. It is much easier than it looks at first. There are plenty of examples online to start with. And the best part is that you can produce interactive charts that allow you to present different views, or different levels of data as you drill into it.